# Apache alias a short extensionless symbol to a file

Tags: apache2, url, alias

I would like to have a short url like:

```
 https://myDomain/essr
```

to evaluate to:

```
 https://myDomain/dir1/dir2/myFile.html
```

I've been trying to use alias in my apache config but I haven't been able to make it work. How would you go about it?

If the file was a php file and I want it to execute what else needs to be done?

Comment: I think you want mod_rewrite but since I am  lazy would use a [`RediredtMatch`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) directive  

   `RedirectMatch “/essr$” “/dir1/dir2/myFile.html”`

Comment: It does the redirect but it would be nice if the url in the browser stayed as https://myDomain/essr

So would mod_rewrite do that?

Comment: Yes indeed mod_rewrite wouldn’t change the url in the browser